# Proper Notation for Set Operations with Intersections of N-circles?

Tags: matrices, elementary-set-theory, notation

Consider sets $A,B,C$ in some space $U$. The sets have common elements shown by the intersections in the Venn's diagram below. Each intersection is unique so the sets $A,B,C,A\cap B, B\cap C,A\cap C$ and $A\cap B\cap C$, abbreviated with A, B, C, AB, BC, AC and ABC, are unique.

[image]

I want to understand how to properly use notation over multiple intersections, can I use the following shorthands with the indexing? My proposal is for any amount $n$ of circles

### n circles

1. Name all parts not in intersection with other components (even the intersections marked in the picture, and define $U$

\begin{equation}
A_{i} = A_{i} \, \backslash \cup_{j \neq i} A_{j}
\end{equation}

2. Intersections (Bjorn)

\begin{equation}
A_{i} = \cap_{i=1}^{n} A_{i}
\end{equation}

3. All other except $\cup_{i} A_{i}$

\begin{equation}
U = \cup_{i=1}^{n} A_{i}^{c}
\end{equation}

Matrix presentation $A_{s}$ for all of those by the upper triangle

\begin{equation}
A_{s} =   
\begin{bmatrix}
    A_{11}       & A_{12} & A_{13} & \dots & A_{1n} & A_{1(n+1)} \\
    0            & A_{22} & A_{23} & \dots & A_{2n} & A_{2(n+1)} \\
    \dots \\
    0            & 0      & 0      & \dots & A_{dn} & A_{d(n+1)}. \\
    0            & 0      & 0      & \dots & 0      & A_{(d+1)(n+1)} 
\end{bmatrix}
\end{equation}

where multi-index values are for intersections by (2). 
The uni-index values ($A_{ii}$) are about (1) in the diagonal. 
The $U$ is $A_{dn}$. 
The matrix proposal for the Venn's diagram where the last column values all except one become zero because the $U$ does not have intersections with $A_{i}$ by (3).

\begin{equation}
A_{s} =   
\begin{bmatrix}
    A_{11}       & A_{12} & A_{13} & \dots & A_{1n} & 0 \\
    0            & A_{22} & A_{23} & \dots & A_{2n} & 0 \\
    \dots \\
    0            & 0      & 0      & \dots & 0      & A_{(n+1)(n+1)}. 
\end{bmatrix}
\end{equation}

### Case n=3

\begin{equation}
A_{s} =   
\begin{bmatrix}
    A_{11}       & A_{12} & A_{13} & 0 \\
    0            & A_{22} & A_{23} & 0 \\
    0            & 0      & A_{33} & 0 \\
    0            & 0      & 0      & A_{44}.
\end{bmatrix}
\end{equation}

Comment: Sorry, what's the question?

Comment: @Rahul this is a notation question for elementary set-theoretic operations, does this indexing notation make sense such as $\cap_{i=1}^3 a_i$ for all subareas crossed by three disks ($A\cap B\cap C$ for the example with the Venn diagram)?

Comment: For me it's not clear what your question is. From the title and the last sentence I infer that you want to know whether $\bigcap\limits_{i=1}^{n} A_i$ is the proper notation for the intersection of $n$ sets $A_1,A_2,\ldots,A_n$. But because you made a long story, I am not sure if this is really what you want to know.

Comment: Name them $A_1 = A$, $A_2 = B$, and $A_3 = C$. Their intersection will be $A \cap B \cap C = \bigcap\limits_{i=1}^{3} A_i$.

Comment: $A - B - C = A - \bigcup\limits_{i=2}^{3} A_i$

Comment: @BjörnFriedrich Please, see the body for the summarised matrix presentation of the components in Venn's diagram? Do you agree?

Comment: @Masi this cannot be true for the general case of the number of different regions. The matrix presention only shows regions where intersection of two circles not intersections of more than two circles. This matrix form would mean that the number of intersections of n circles in O(n)=n^2 where n is the number of circles -- which is false, the number of intersections I have a feeling is exponential with respect to n.

Answer (score 1):

**Definitions**

You want to learn different complement operations [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complement_(set_theory)). Notice that relative complement and absolute complement are two different things. The absolute complement noted with C, like $A^c$ (all other elements except elements of A i.e. $$A^c=\{x\in U\mid x\not\in A\},$$ while relative complement for sets $A$ and $B$

$$B\backslash A= B\cap A^c$$

where all elements of $B$ not in $A$. The minus sign you use should be a backslash.

[image]

The triangle stands for [symmetric difference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric_difference) $A\triangle B$, all elements of $A$ and $B$ such that they have no common elements so removing the intersection area.

[image]

---

**Answer to the question**

Consider the A,B and C picture in the question. The union of the subareas having no intersections are a relative complement of three sets. It could be marked with $$U-A_1\cap A_2-A_1\cap A_3-A_2\cap A_3$$ when you mark the disks with $A_1$, $A_2$ and $A_3$. And the general case is given by [Inclusion Exclusion Principle](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle).

Comment: @Masi the minus sign you use should be a backslash, for typographic reasons, people sometimes use the minus. I would suggest to stick with the tradition of the backslash

Comment: @Masi absolute complement of $A$ is just a set $A^c$ having all elements except the elements of $A$, actually relative complement with respect to $U$ i.e. $U\backslash A$, all elements of $U$ where elements of $A$ are removed. The absolute complement is actually a relative complement of $A$ and $U$ while relative complement defined for any sets $A$ and $B$ such that $A\backslash B$ i.e. all elements of $A$ but no elements of $B$ in the set. So you are interested in relative complements of sets A, B and C?

Comment: @Masi Scroll directly to special case or generalisation of [Exclusion Inclusion Principle](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion–exclusion_principle), also mentioned in my thesis...by this you find a closed form matematical espression.

Comment: Please, see the body.

Comment: @Masi your proposition only applies to regions of two intersecting disks, not to the general case where intersections of different number of disks possible. The general case does not have O(n)=n^2 number of intersections as this presentation would imply.